# Should mobile ask for taps on spoilers, not clicks?

Tags: bug, user-interface, spoilers

The spoiler

> WELL HELLO!

currently reads on mobile devices "Click to show spoiler"

[image: spoiler on mobile]

On desktop devices, the spoiler appears as an empty blockquote, like this:

[image: spoiler on desktop]

Should the spoiler warning say "**Tap** to reveal" rather than "Click"? Or should I keep longer fingernails?

Comment: What about a desktop with touch-enabled monitor?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver if it’s like the ones I’ve used, it by default will definitely use the desktop site.

Comment: @Stormblessed he means how can we resolve whether to ask for a "Tap" or a "Click" .. GypsySpellweaver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver it'll act like the full site, provided the screen is large enough. If you toggle over to the responsive theme, there's no text on spoilers there, even on mobile. It's an empty block quote that responds to clicks