# Show "Tap to show spoiler" message for spoilers in responsive design

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, responsive-design, touch-screen

Related question: [Should mobile ask for taps on spoilers, not clicks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338064/295232), but that is about the (deprecated) mobile web interface, not the new responsive design. [This feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104085/295232) is related but [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and I'm not asking for it to be implemented on desktops. Not as many people were using touch screens to browse Stack Exchange back then, and the new responsive design has been explicitly designed to accommodate touch screens.

---

Now to the feature request itself: I realized there that it's rather easy on desktop to discover how to interact with spoilers; when you point your mouse at it, the contents will appear on hovering over it. This might even happen accidentally; the animation will get your attention anyway. Many (new) users are using Stack Exchange on their smartphone or tablet, where this interaction is simply not possible. As [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337984/295232) mentions, it just looks like somebody made a mistake and posted an empty blockquote.

Because the new responsive design will (eventually) replace the old [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) interface, can it show the "<s>Click</s> Tap to show spoiler" message as well if the [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format_for_human-operated_web_browsers) indicates it's a mobile device?

[image]

Comment: Yes, please: [Use spoilers from mobile theme on regular sites too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138952/use-spoilers-from-mobile-theme-on-regular-sites-too).

Comment: That's about the (old) mobile web interface, which has a different codebase which isn't maintained anymore. And Arjan's question (from before the responsive design was introduced) asks to enable it for all devices, while I think it's not necessary for the desktop view.

Comment: @Glorfindel It's functionally identical. Both questions are asking to have *click* replaced with *tap* on mobile devices *only*. In fact, the other question only says *mobile*. It says nothing about which particular software backend is being used. The other question very likely could be asking for exactly the same thing as this question.